# Cascade not working on doctrine with OneToMany

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm working on symfony 4.2.11 and I need to persist a PageTemplate entity. However, this entity contains PageTemplateBlock entities that must be updated in database. The PageTemplateBlock entity contains PageTemplateBlockProfiled, PageTemplateBlockView, and PageBlockItemVersion entities that must also be updated.

At first everything worked fine except that the PageBockItemVersion entities were removed by cascade.
 
So, I tried to get the list of my PageBlockItemVersion to persist (it's dirty) ..

And here I am stuck for an SQL integrity constraint ... Doctrine deletes my entities correctly but it inserts a PageTemplateBlock before the PageTemplate --'

Results:

[SQL queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXr4K.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2VO7.png)

PageTemplate

```
<?php

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var Site
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site", inversedBy="pageTemplates")
 */
private $site;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlock[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlock", mappedBy="template", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"order"="ASC"})
 */
private $blocks;

/**
 * @var PageVersion[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageVersion", mappedBy="pageTemplate", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $pageVersions;
```

PageTemplateBlock

```
<?php

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var PageTemplate
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageTemplate", inversedBy="blocks")
 */
private $template;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="_order")
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlockProfiled[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlockProfiled", mappedBy="block", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $profiledData;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlockView[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlockView", mappedBy="block", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $views;

/**
 * @var PageBlockItemVersion[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PageBlockItemVersion", mappedBy="pageTemplateBlock", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $pageItems;
```

PageTemplateBlockProfiled

```
<?php

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlock
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlock", inversedBy="profiledData")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="block_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $block;

/**
 * @var Profile
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="profiledItems")
 */
private $profile;

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $node;
```

PageTemplateBlockView

```
<?php

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlock
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlock", inversedBy="views")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="block_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $block;

/**
 * @var View
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="View", inversedBy="pageTemplateBlock")
 */
private $view;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="_order")
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @var bool
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $locked;

/**
 * @var array|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $data;
```

PageBlockItemVersion

```
<?php

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var PageVersion
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageVersion", inversedBy="items")
 */
private $pageVersion;

/**
 * @var PageTemplateBlock
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageTemplateBlock", inversedBy="pageVersions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_template_block_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $pageTemplateBlock;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="_order")
 */
private $order;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * @var View
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="View", inversedBy="pageBlockItems")
 */
private $view;
```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is an english speaking site. Questions _have to be_ phrased in the english language.

Comment: Avoid to use screenshots, especially to show error stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell, you're doing *way too much cascading*.

> Cascade operations are performed in memory. That means collections and related entities are fetched into memory (even if they are marked as lazy) when the cascade operation is about to be performed. This approach allows entity lifecycle events to be performed for each of these operations.
>
> However, pulling object graphs into memory on cascade can cause considerable performance overhead, especially when the cascaded collections are large. Make sure to weigh the benefits and downsides of each cascade operation that you define.
>
> *To rely on the database level cascade operations for the delete operation **instead**, you can configure each join column with the onDelete option.*
>
> (emphasis: mine, source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html)

As far as I can tell, you're deleting a `BlockView` (where `block_id=409`, from your screenshot), which has a reference to a block (id=409), which gets deleted at the same time, since you marked the `block` join column with `onDelete="CASCADE"`. Then you try to insert a `BlockView` for that block (`block_id=409`), which doesn't exist anymore, hence it causes the foreign key error.

The cited docs say, cascades are performed in memory. I would stick to that and just remove the `onDelete` option on your join columns, because it appears to confuse doctrine enough ... in any case, stick to one method of cascading. I would prefer the doctrine method, for all the events and overall consistency and integrity.